# TextView's bounds issue

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview, frame, bounds

I have a view with pan gesture recognizer,which invokes this method

```
- (IBAction)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
translation = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:self.trackingView];
bounds = self.myTextView.bounds;
newBoundsOriginY = (bounds.origin.y - translation.y)/3.52;
self.myTextView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0,newBoundsOriginY);
//[self.myTextView scrollRectToVisible:bounds animated:NO];
}
```

As you can see I also have a textView and I want to scroll the textView using gesture recognizer.It works, but the problem occurs when I perform new dragging gesture.When I do this I get textView's `bounds.origin` always `(0,0)`.So textView remains it's bounds until the new drag begins.Why?

Does anybody know why textView's `bounds.origin` returns to `CGPointZero` every time this method is invoked? Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe this has to do with Frame versus Bounds. `bounds` is in reference to the view itself, whereas `frame` is with reference to the parent view, so maybe you want to consider moving the view with respect to its parent: i.e. use `frame` instead of (or in conjunction with) `bounds`.

Comment: @KonsolLabapen Nope. I need exactly to scroll the text view, I don't want to change it's position in superview's coordinate system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533317/is-there-any-way-i-can-scroll-uitextview-from-other-view/25548067#25548067) solves the problem.You need set translation to `CGPointZero` every time you handle gesture.Otherwise it is concatenated.