# Is there any way I can scroll UITextView from other view?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uitextview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UITextView` and a simple blank view with `UIPanGestureRecognizer` in it. The idea behind this was the following: I make a pan gesture in blank view, gesture recognizer detects it and scrolls the text view (by `scrollToVisibleRect` or smth like that). Is there any other way? I am asking because [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494260/textviews-bounds-issue/this) is not resolved yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, Logan's answer is right. Although, I would like to add this:
You need to subtract(not add) the y component of translation. So the code should look like this:

```
currentOffset.y -= [pan translationInView:pan.view].y;
```

And then you must prevent `contentOffset`'s being more than your textView's `contentSize.height`.Just add this:

```
CGFloat minOffset = 0.0;
CGFloat maxOffset = self.myTextView.contentSize.height - self.myTextView.bounds.size.height;

self.myTextView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0,fmax(minOffset, fmin(currentOffset.y, maxOffset)));
```

And yes,this line is VERY important

```
`[gestureRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:gestureRecognizer.view];`
```

Why? Apple says in the :

`- (CGPoint)translationInView:(UIView *)view`

The x and y values report the total translation over time. **They are not delta values** from the last time that the translation was reported. **Apply** the **translation** value to the state of the view **when** the gesture is **first** recognized—do not concatenate the value each time the handler is called.

For further info, you'd better read [this](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/04/understanding-uiscrollview/).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the content offset of your textView, just like any other scrollView.  Try something like this:

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pan
{
    if (pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        CGPoint offset = self.textView.contentOffset;
        offset.y += [pan translationInView:pan.view].y;
        self.textView.contentOffset = offset;
    }
    [pan setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:pan.view];
}
```

I haven't tested this, so there might be some small issues.  This should at least get you pointed in the right direction.  Let me know if you have updates/questions.